# pushing object onto stack

Tags: java, stack

I have this code for pushing an object onto the stack, I am having trouble with understanding what each line does, if someone could explain why the previous node (newNode.next) has to be equal to top, and why then making top equal to the newNode.

```
void push(AnyClass newbObj)
{
  Node newNode = Node(newObj);
  newNode.next = top;
  top = newNode;
}
```

Comment: **Try it with pen and paper.**

Comment: Look at the definition of Node, and, in particular, the field `next` in it.

Comment: And read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I have tried it on pen and paper also

Comment: It's not actually a stack, it's a linked list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a linked list implementation.  In a linked list each item has a pointer (reference) to the next one in the list.

The variable `top` seems to be a reference to the node at the beginning of the list and therefore represents the top of the stack.

Let's assume then that the list starts looking like this:

```
item 1 -> item 2 -> etc...
^----top
```

The first line is just casting the parameter to the right type, we could instead have defined `push()` to take a `Node` instead and remove this line altogether.

Since we want to insert the new node at the front, firstly we need to ensure it points to the rest of the list using:

```
newNode.next = top;  //Point newNode's 'next' field to the current top of the list
```

This gives us something that looks like this

```
newNode -> item 1 -> item 2 -> etc...
           ^----top
```

But `top` is still pointing to the old item, so we now update that:

```
top = newNode; //Re-assign top to point to the new head of the list
```

Now the list looks like this:

```
newNode -> item 1 -> item 2 -> etc...
^----top
```

And we're done.

Answer (score 1):

Let me Explain you in steps:

> 1. newNode is a new node created using code `Node newNode = Node(newObj);`.And you want to put it on the top of stack (i.e. push)
> 2. Right now on top of stack you have other node called top.
> 3. You want to push the current top node to one step down
> 4. you link the new node to the current top node in following code.
>
>    `newNode.next = top`
> 5. Thereafter you make the new node as the top of stack in following code:
>
>    `top = newNode`

**EDIT**

> Some emphasize on line 4.
>
> `newNode.next = top` means `newNode` has a variable named 
>   `next`
>
> which is going to store the `memory address` of previous Top node .
>   So that if we want to access previous top node via current Top node
>   (`newNode`) we could do it easily by:
>
> `Node prevTopNode = (Node)top.next`

Comment: in step 4 why is the new node newNode.next though ?

Comment: So that the chain of nodes are kept entact. it is like: top node is holding 2nd node. 2nd node is holding 3rd node . 3rd is holding 4rth and so on... It can be visualized as top->2nd->3rd->4rth->...->nth node

Answer (score 0):

I added some comments, hope that helps.

```
void push(AnyClass newbObj)
{
  Node newNode = Node(newObj);  //create a new node of the stack containing the data (newbObj)
  newNode.next = top;           //the new node has thw prevois top of the stack the successor 
  top = newNode;                //the new node is now the top of the tsack
}
```